# I don’t understand why use headless service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, headless-service

Many sites like this says that the benefit of Headless Service is direct detection of the pod’s IP address and direct access to the pod.
However, this explanation does not make sense to me. The reason is that even if we don’t use the Headless Service, we can still access the pod directly.

I think the following example:

- 1 pod(this is client)
- 3 pod managed by StatefulSet

1. using headless service

```py
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-headless-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: my-statefulset
spec:
  serviceName: my-headless-service
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-container
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
---
# Client Pod
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    name: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp
    image: willfarrell/ping
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
```

From the Pod named myapp-pod, we can access each Pods managed by StatefulSet like the following

```py
ping my-statefulset-0.my-headless-service
ping my-statefulset-1.my-headless-service
ping my-statefulset-2.my-headless-service
```

1. without headless service

```py
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: my-statefulset
spec:
  serviceName: my-service
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-container
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
---
# Client Pod
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    name: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp
    image: willfarrell/ping
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
```

From the Pod named myapp-pod, we can also access each Pods managed by StatefulSet like the following

```py
ping my-statefulset-0.my-service
ping my-statefulset-1.my-service
ping my-statefulset-2.my-service
```

Like this we can access  Pods managed by StatefulSet without headless service.

Is there any difference between 1(using headless service) and 2(without headless service)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A headless service is a non-loadbalanced service with no CluserIP, so it cannot be exposed outside the cluster. This also provides security to your key services
- It is useful when a client wants to connect to one or all the pods at once - DBs such as MongoDB perform replication leveraging headless services
- When you query a headless service, you get the IPs of all the pods (dynamically) behind the service not just for 1 pod as in case of a regular service.
- In your example, you need to know how many pods are there and their FQDNs ahead of time. Without a headless service it is neither ideal not dynamic.

Great article for further exploration:
https://www.goglides.dev/bkpandey/headless-services-in-kubernetes-what-why-and-how-39fl